# element-wise multiplication of two vectors in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do the following mathematical operation with two vectors:

```
v1 = [a1][a2][a3][a4][a5]
v2 = [b1][b2][b3][b4]b5]
```

Want to compute:

```
v = [a2*b2][a3*b3][a4*b4][a5*b5]
```

Note that I did not want the first element in the new vector.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient (one-liner) way to multiply (element-wise) two vectors in c++ than a for-loop (using push back).  My current approach is as follows,

```
for(long i=1;i < v1.size();++i){
v.push_back(v1[i]*v2[i]);
}
```

I also tried the following,

```
 for (long i = 1; i < v1.size(); ++i){
     v[i-1] = v1[i]*v2[i];
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a particularly large array? If so, a better optimisation may be do use parallel code than to optimise this small piece of code.

Comment: @PhilH it is large but more than that I have to do (in serial) this operation million's of times.

Comment: If you write it as a standard loop (and perhaps if you use iterators?) the compiler can unroll the loop for you to speed it up. Since you know the size of the final vector beforehand, please use vec.reserve() before the loop so that you don't trigger reallocations. The best advice, though, is to measure the performance and look at where it is actually spending time. Reallocs are one example of unexpected timesinks.

Comment: Also, if you have a lot of this kind of linear algebra to do, look at using a BLAS implementation from your chip manufacturer; it will be the best-optimised implementation of linear algebra operations available.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
std::transform( v1.begin()+1, v1.end(),
                v2.begin()+1, v.begin(),  // assumes v1,v2 of same size > 1, 
                                          //       v one element smaller
                std::multiplies<int>() ); // assumes values are 'int'
```

You can replace `v.begin()` with [`std::back_inserter(v)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) if `v` is empty, you should `reserve()` memory upfront to avoid multiple allocations.

Comment: Is this more efficient? After all you need to iterate through each element and multiply, no matter who  does this operation for you.

Comment: @axiom: From the description "*more efficient (one-liner)*" I understand that the OP is considering one-liner to be more efficient than multiple lines. If *efficiency* is measured in real performance (cpu), there is no trivial solution in the general case. Depending on the inputs you might be able to use vectorized operations, but that has stronger requirements on the input and output data.

Comment: +1 "You can replace v.begin() with `std::back_inserter(v)`" Now that's better!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas thanks!  looks nice!  yeah when I said more efficient I meant both, maybe more OP-like, and maybe (if possible) more efficient in CPU... but this seems good enough to my needs so far.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas hmm. In general source code and efficiency have no direct relation but i have seen the points getting mixed a lot. If we consider a single CPU, one *cannot* do better than iterating through the input. However, on a machine that supports any *form* of parallelism, OP can gain a lot as this problems lies close to what are called [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems. The gains may be as much as the number of processing elements employed.

Answer (score 13):

You could look into [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray). It's designed to allow mathematical operations on every element in the array.